# JTextField limit characters while typing without showing last unwanted character

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keyevent, keyrelease

Scenario:

- In the db there are existing lengthy words for this textField. I want to load that data when I do an update task.
- But when I try to edit that lengthy word, it should trim to limited size(get a subString from that word).

Due to the above 2 points, I can not limit the text length directly. And also I want following thing.

- When I type a new character for that trimmed word, last character should not show. It means currently I am using a keyRelease event, So I can see the last character which I typed before JAVA code check the length. Therefor I want a way to find the length of the word without showing that unwanted character.

Please help me to find a better way to solve this.

Comment: You should not trim the value while the user is typing, but rather should trim the value after it is committed.  A [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) is the best choice for this.

Comment: I'm not really understanding your requirement. Maybe give an example of 1) the text from the database 2) how it is automatically resized and a substring of the text is displayed in the text field 3) Maybe you can use a DocumentFilter. The Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) has a working example that limits the size of the text.

Comment: 1) text from the db means I want to show length words in this text field, length limit not applicable for these lengthy words which already exist in the db. 
2)automatically rezice(get the sub string) when user tries to edit the text. In here I used a key release event. But the problem is if I want 10 characters I can see 11th character when I type that. Bcz I used key release event. User should not see that 11th character when he type that. 

I’ll try to use DocumentFilter. Thanks.